# Displaying the categories with their posts?

Tags: php, sql, archive

I am trying to get my codes to display as such:

**Category 1**

Post 1
Post 3

**Category 2**
Post 2

**Category 3**
No posts in Category

```
$catQuery = "SELECT * FROM category";

$titleQuery = "SELECT a.article_id, a.title, ac.article_id, ac.category_id, c.category_id, c.category
        FROM category c, article a, article_category ac
        WHERE a.article_id = ac.article_id
        AND ac.category_id = c.category_id
        ORDER BY category ASC , a.article_id ASC";
```

I have two queries above. I do know how to 'while loop' to echo out the category, but I'm not sure how to incorporate my second set of query to display like above.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned a loop which is what you need. In pseudo-code:

```
$categories = query('select * from categories');

foreach( $categories as $cat ){
  $sql = $db->prepare('select * from articles where category_id = ?', $cat['id'])
}
```